# Why isn't there a "<--" operator?

Tags: c

I was going through K&R C book and got through this `-->` operator in the precedence table. So, I wondered if there was a similar operator i.e., `<--` and wrote the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int x = 5;
   while(0 <-- x)
       printf("%d",x);
}
```

It worked perfectly fine. So why isn't <-- is not considered as an operator? (as it is not in the precedence table!) and what is it's precedence?

Comment: Where you find that table? Let us know about that.

Comment: Sorry mistake thought it was `-->` but it is `->` :3

Comment: In addition to `<--`, you can also extend the length of the arrow: `<--------` or `------>` etc

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`-->` is not one operator, it is two; (post) decrement and less than. C is whitespace agnostic for the most part, so:

```
x --> y
/* is the same as */
x-- > y
```

`<--` is the same idea:

```
x <-- y
/* is the same as */
x < --y
```

---

Perhaps you are confusing `->` with `-->`.  `->` dereferences a pointer to get at a member of the type it refers to.

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
} foo;

int main(void)
{
    foo f = {1};
    foo *fp = &f;
    printf("%d", fp->x);
    return 0;
}
```

`<-` is simply not an operator at all.

Comment: Re "*`<-` is simply not an operator at all.*", But it can be part of valid code. In the same spirit of `<--`, there's `x <- 4` (`x < -4`).

Answer (score 3):

This is not an operator but two operators: `<` and `--`. The code is identical to

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int x = 5;
   while(0 < --x)
       printf("%d",x);
}
```

Comment: if it isn't an aoperator , why is it listed in K&R C precedence table?

Comment: @PruthviRaj: It's not. Did you mean `->` which dereferences a pointer?

Comment: Oops! my bad then i thought it was `-->` :3

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, that is just a "less than" < operator followed by decreasing the variable x (--). It is not one operator, but two. And -- has precedence over <.